# Why didn't Sauron become a super nice guy after making the One Ring?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, movie

Sauron apparently imbued the One Ring with all of his evil.

> *"But they were all of them deceived, for another ring was made: in the
>   land of Mordor, in the fires of Mount Doom, the dark lord Sauron
>   forged, in secret, a master ring to control all others. And **into this
>   ring he poured his cruelty, his malice,and his will to dominate all
>   life."***
>
> <sub><sup>https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Talk:The_Lord_of_the_Rings_(movies)</sup></sub>

Why didn't he turn into a really nice guy afterwards if all of his evil was in the ring?

Comment: If he didn't literally transfer malice into the ring then what did he literally do to cause the ring to be caustic to the bearer's mind?

Comment: I don't know if you've ever dealt with an evil overlord, but it's not like they all have a secret side yearning for unicorns and kittens that will magically burst forth in sparkles and rainbows once they run out of Evil Gas.

Comment: If I built an evil "movie-reviewing AI" and poured all of my hatred for the Transformers films into it, that doesn't mean I stop hating them, just that I've created something else that hates them the same amount.

Comment: The ring corrupted him.

Comment: Why can't he make the ring maleficent without having to get malice from some where to fill it?

Comment: @Cugel I like your response the best

Comment: He didn't pour all into it just enough to be sufficiently evil.

Comment: You appear to be interpreting that line in a way as if Sauron has a bucket inside his being, which can hold only a specific quantity of cruelty, malice, and will to dominate. And when he crafted the One Ring, he literally (figuratively) poured this bucket into the Ring's being. I don't think that's how emotions work.

Comment: I actually laughed out loud at this question. Besides the fact that quote is rubbish the point of putting much (not all) of himself in it was so **he could Rule them all** (he did this to the Nazgûl - deceiving them and they gain power until they fade forever - but the elves not only knew immediately they had been deceived but they also never used them when he had it). You know: 'One Ring to rule them all, One Ring to find them, One Ring to bring them all and in the darkness bind them'.

Comment: If you see someone without a smile, give them yours. You still get to keep it, and you may get one from them.

Answer (score 12):

Evil is not a zero sum resource in Tolkien's world that must be apportioned between individual beings. This is made evident throughout his work, for example by descriptions of *really evil* beings like Melkor/Morgoth or Sauron corrupting others. In fact, Sauron, once an angelic fire spirit (a Maia) in the service to Aulë back when the world was being created in Tolkien's legendarium (see "The Valaquenta" in *The Silmarillion*), was corrupted by Melkor.

Another example is the creation of the race of Orcs (as published in *The Silmarillion*, a subject Tolkien was torn about in later Letters):

> So it came to pass, some years ere the coming of Oromë, that if any of the Elves strayed far abroad, alone or few together, they would often vanish, and never return… But of those unhappy ones who were ensnared by Melkor little is known of a certainty… Yet this is held true by the wise of Eressëa, that all those of the Quendi [i.e. Elves] who came into the hands of Melkor, ere Utumno was broken, were put there in prison, and by slow arts of cruelty were **corrupted and enslaved; and thus did Melkor breed the hideous race of the Orcs in envy and mockery of the Elves, of whom they were afterwards the bitterest foes**. For the Orcs had life and multiplied after the manner of the Children of Ilúvatar; and naught that had life of its own, nor the semblance of life, could ever Melkor make since his rebellion in the Ainulindalë before the Beginning: so say the wise. And deep in their dark hearts the Orcs loathed the Master whom they served in fear, the maker only of their misery. This it may be was the vilest deed of Melkor, and the most hateful to Ilúvatar. (emphasis added)
>
> —The Coming of the Elves and the Captivity of Melkor, *The Silmarillion*

Melkor was not made less evil, or more good by creating the Orcs, but their creation was a manifestation of his evil. Indeed, Tolkien described *all* evil in the world as having its origin ultimately in Melkor. Tolkien *never* describes such acts as redistribution of evil as a finite resource, but as the creation of *new* evil where it did not exist before.

Comment: Well, in all seriousness, the idea of evil as a finite quantity is a novel (ahem) one and goes against all common sense. It's an interesting idea for a novel, but it's not the one that Tolkein wrote.

Comment: I think this is why the question is being downvoted into oblivion.

Comment: I'm almost certain that it was before the Letters that he was torn about what races Morgoth corrupted but I know at one point he suggested both Men and Elves; but he wrote about it in the letters later on.